# search in postgresql with a wildcard

Tags: postgresql

In a postgres view i want to add a view where the time is bronze age. The problem is that there are different kinds of bronze ages( for example: bronze age early and bronze time late). I tried to find all the bronze ages with use of wildcard but i m doing something wrong.

I have the following data in column temporal_abr:

```
Bronze_age laat: 1100 - 800 vC
Bronze_age late 1100 - 800 vC and Iron_age: 800 - 12 vC
Bronze_age: 2000 - 800 vC and Iron_age: 800 - 12 vC
Iron_age late: 250 - 12 vC
Medieval late: 1050 - 1500 nC and Bronze_age late: 1100 - 800 vC
```

I want to get all the record where Bronze_age exist. I trief to do this with the following SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dans_tijd AS 
    SELECT import_tijd.dans_code,
    import_tijd.temporal_abr,
    geom_tijd.geom AS geometry,
   FROM import_tijd
   JOIN geom_tijd ON import_tijd.dans_code = geom_tijd.dans_code 
   where import_tijd.temporal_abr LIKE 'Bronze_age%'
```

keep in mind that there is a space between bronze_age late. can somebody help me?

Comment: Use `%` instead of `*`

Comment: thanks for the response , I changed it to what you said but I still dont get any result. Is the problem that there are spaces?

Comment: @B.Termeer provide a sample data from the table, the results you are getting and what do you expect to get.

Comment: @elad i added some sample data

Comment: @B.Termeer What type is temporal_abr?, you didnt write what your query gives and what is the expected result.

Comment: @elad i found out what the problem was. I mispelled something. The % character was the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%` instead of `*` and change the `=` to `ILIKE` or `LIKE`

```
   WHERE import_tijd.temporal_abr ILIKE 'bronze_age%'
```

`ILIKE` is if letters are case sensitive, otherwise use `LIKE`

You can read about it in the
[Manual refrence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html)

**Edit:** Following your sample data:

```
WHERE import_tijd.temporal_abr ILIKE 'bronze_age%'
```

Will give:

```
Bronze_age laat: 1100 - 800 vC
Bronze_age late 1100 - 800 vC and Iron_age: 800 - 12 vC
Bronze_age: 2000 - 800 vC and Iron_age: 800 - 12 vC
```

if you add `%` at the begining, you will get everything that contains the text  `bronze_age`.

```
   WHERE import_tijd.temporal_abr ILIKE '%bronze_age%'
```

Will give:

```
Bronze_age laat: 1100 - 800 vC
Bronze_age late 1100 - 800 vC and Iron_age: 800 - 12 vC
Bronze_age: 2000 - 800 vC and Iron_age: 800 - 12 vC
Medieval late: 1050 - 1500 nC and Bronze_age late: 1100 - 800 vC
```